# Is the C# compiler version in a Mono distribution the same as the Mono version?

Tags: c#, version

I want to know which version of Mono I have loaded. I know the C# compiler version (C# compiler version echos to screen when I initiate compile using csc command on a filename.cs script file). But is this the same as Mono version?

I have seen the compiler version when I compile a new filename.cs script file, but the --version extension does not work with Mono. I loaded Mono from the official Mono download page, using those instructions.

Here is an example of how the C# compiler version shows up when I compile a script file:

$ csc hello.cs
Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 2.8.2.62916 (2ad4aabc)
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

$ mono hello.exe
returned the correct reply:
Hello Mono World

So I know which version of the Microsoft C# compiler is present, but I do not know what version of Mono I have loaded. How do I find the Mono version? Is it the same as the C# compiler version?

Answer (score 0):

```
mono --version
```

That shell command will give you the version